# good preparation material on java WebSphere portals

Tags: java

Where can i find good preparation material on java WebSphere portals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with the [IBM documentation](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/Documentation/Software/WebSphere/WebSphere_Portal) (in particular, the [Infocenter](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/lotus/support/information-centers/#Portal) and the [Redbooks](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/cgi-bin/searchsite.cgi?query=websphere+portal+AND+6&SearchOrder=1&SearchFuzzy=)). If you want API and tooling references, look at the [RAD documentation](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/Documentation/Software/Rational/Rational_Application_Developer_for_WebSphere_Software) ([portlet dev with 7.5.5](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.etools.portal.doc/topics/cportaletover.html)).